# Xdebug dont stop if used from web-worker?

Tags: javascript, php, xdebug, web-worker

Is it possible that Xdebug doesn't stop in breakpoints if requests started from inside a web-worker?
I'm doing a fetch() request.

```
fetch(datatable_instance_defaults.pathToSqlFile + 'returnSqlRes.php',
    {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'text/plain',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        method: "post",
        body: JSON.stringify(sql)
    })
    .then(function (res) {
        return res.json();
    })
```

Comment: How do you enable a request to work with xdebug? Do you use the GET parameters XDEBUG_SESSION_START or do you use a browser extension like easyXdebug?

Comment: As @KevinDitscheid said -- either pass "debug this" marker (cookie or GET/POST parameter) so that xdebug knows that it should debug this request .... or configure xdebug to attempt to debug every single request (`xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in your php.ini).

Comment: i use browser extension . Thanks LazyOne , ill try it @home cause its a side project that i have...

Answer (score 4):

Since the web-worker API has no access to the session storage according to the [DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope) your Xdebug session cookie can not be passed along to the server, thus it does not recognize your open Xdebug session from the main thread.

You could temporarily add the `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` GET parameter to your URL to start a new Xdebug session. (see [the documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote) of xdebug, too)

```
fetch(datatable_instance_defaults.pathToSqlFile + 'returnSqlRes.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=session_name',
```

It is a little inconvenient to do it this way, but I imagine that the plugin developers need to figure out a way to keep the Xdebug session or restart it for service-worker requests.